How can I make an element overflow equally in every direction?
I'm having a lot of trouble with this issue. I'm trying to create a Canva-like drawing sheet that can be zoomed in and out. The problem is that when I zoom in, the sheet enlarges, but it distorts according to the page dimensions. Instead, I want it to overflow equally in all directions based on its size, so it remains centered on the page, just like in the Canva app. How can I achieve this feature using CSS?
I tried everything I know about CSS (not so much), but I can't find any solution. Can someone show me a little example?

This specific answer is mostly focused on your question title, not related to zooming, but initially scrolling a parent element to center.
Not sure if that's achievable using pure CSS (and i.e: scroll-snap), but a simple way with a line of JavaScript would be to use scrollIntoView with block and inline properties set to "center". Such will center the desired child element inside the overflow scroll parent — on page load.


document.querySelector("#area").scrollIntoView({
  block: 'center',
  inline: 'center',
});
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

#viewport {
  height: 100dvh; /* Any needed height */
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
  container-type: size;
  background: #232425;
}

#area {
  width: 180cqw;
  height: 180cqh;
  display: flex;
}

#canvas {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80cqw; 
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;  /* Or any user-defined ratio */
  background: white;
}
<div id="viewport">
  <div id="area">
    <div id="canvas" contenteditable>Edit me!</div>
  </div>
</div>



Then, regarding zooming from point, for a proper way to create such a UI like i.e: Photoshop or Canva does, you might be interested in: Create a zoomable area like photoshop
